# What does `CALIB_CHECK_COND` flag of the OpenCV function fisheye::calibrate() do?

Tags: c++, opencv

In the [OpenCV documentation for fisheye::calibrate](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/db/d58/group__calib3d__fisheye.html#gad626a78de2b1dae7489e152a5a5a89e1) it says that turning on the flag `fisheye::CALIB_CHECK_COND` means that "the functions will check validity of condition number", but I have no idea what that means.

Here is the [source code for fisheye.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/calib3d/src/fisheye.cpp).

What does `CALIB_CHECK_COND` flag exactly do?

This flag is also relevant for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038464/opencv-calibrate-fisheye-lens-error-ill-conditioned-matrix), but no one seemed to have figured it out.