# OpenCV create undistorted images from different perspectives

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a 180 degree fisheye camera, and I want to obtain an undistorted image with as wide a field of view as possible. Eventually, I want to be able to use this to create a 180 degree top down image using the fisheye camera. To do this, I want to first undistort the image while retaining as much image data as I can.

I used the opencv fisheye.calibrate in python using chessboard images taken at different angles, and that correctly undistorts a fisheye image, giving me a decent result. However, the resulting image has a significantly worse field of view than the fisheye image due to how it undistorts the image.

**Fisheye image**:

[image]

**Undistorted Image Lacking field of view**:

[image]

**Current code**:

```
DIM=(960, 540)
K=np.array([[263.1021173128426, 0.0, 477.98780306608234], [0.0, 261.30612719984185, 300.714230825097], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
D=np.array([[-0.0007727739728155351], [-0.10019345132548932], [0.10790597488851726], [-0.040655761660861996]])
def undistort(img):
    h,w = img.shape[:2]
    map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
    return cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

It is my understanding that there is no way to increase the field of view of the undistortion output without having the output be stretched into an undesirable shape (e.g. [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9kgs.jpg)). However, I have seen people able to create mutliple undistorted images from different perspectives. For example given the original fisheye image above, I want to be able to create images from different perspectives such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBWkM.png) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCXmh.png), which could then be stitched together for a wider field of view. Is there a way to adjust the calibration parameters of the opencv undistortion function to achieve this?

I am assuming this is possible as I have seen it done in other contexts such as [here (using java and boofCV)](https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Fisheye_To_Pinhole).

Any advice on alternate ways of achieving a wider field of view would be appreciated as well.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53500300/10699171) may be of some use

Comment: @J.D. I have looked at that answer, and while that is one way of processing a fisheye image, I am more specifically looking for a method in opencv to generate multiple pinhole images at different angles from a fisheye image. Thanks though.

Comment: @person132 did you find a solution to your problem?