# initUndistortRectifyMap gives wrong image

Tags: opencv, fisheye, python

I faced with difficulties when trying to get result similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316306/opencv-fisheye-calibration-cuts-too-much-of-the-resulting-image?newreg=1f0cebfca8df4fb4a293327e9dc4785f).
After [camera calibration](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0) I obtained the following parameters:

```
DIM=(800, 600)
K=np.array([[177.41548430658207, 0.0, 258.68599972062486], [0.0, 177.57591422482173, 205.71268583567885], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0]])
D=np.array([[-0.04397357230351177], [-0.03399404486757072], [0.03174104028771482], [-0.01131815456157867]])
```

My initial fish-eye image looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHblO.png).

With the following code:

```
def undistort(img_path):
    img = cv2.imread(img_path)
    nk = K.copy()
    nk[0,0]=K[0,0]
    nk[1,1]=K[1,1]
    map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), nk, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)  
    undistorted_img = cv2.remap( img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
    cv2.imshow("undistorted", undistorted_img)
    cv2.imwrite('recoPersp_wrong.jpg', undistorted_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

reconstructed perspective image looks
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awWEr.jpg). 
However by changing:

```
nk[0,0]=K[0,0]
nk[1,1]=K[1,1]
```

to

```
nk[0,0]=K[0,0]/2
nk[1,1]=K[1,1]/2
```

I don't get desired result as described by [Hello Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316306/opencv-fisheye-calibration-cuts-too-much-of-the-resulting-image?newreg=1f0cebfca8df4fb4a293327e9dc4785f). Instead my image is blurred and smeared on the edges [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Eiqt.jpg) (it is different image but still the same problem)
Could you please tell me what am I doing wrong?